# missing right parenthesis problems

Tags: oracle

i didn't know what the problem is. First this one works fine in sql

```
 create table Department
(Department_Id number(8) PRIMARY KEY ,
Dept_Name varchar(20),
Location varchar(20));
```

but the second one says missing right parenthesis ora-00907

```
create table Instructor(Instructor_ID number(8) PRIMARY KEY ,
 Department_Id number(8) FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES Department(Department_Id) ,
 Ins_name varchar2(20) ,
 Position varchar(20) ,
 email_Id varchar (40),
 Contact_No number(10),
Date_Of_Joining date);
```

Comment: There are no parentheses missing; I'm not able to reproduce your problem.

Comment: If your error happens to be due to a typo consider removing the question since "typo questions" are usually too specific to be of any help to others.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Leave out the FOREIGN KEY part:

```
Department_Id number(8) REFERENCES Department(Department_Id) ,
```

See [Oracle FAQs](http://www.orafaq.com/wiki/Foreign_key) for an example.  The FOREIGN KEY keywords are for out-of-line constraints, which go after the column definitions.